# How to change the Header divider in context menu in Android programmatically

Tags: android

I have made a context menu dynamically. And I can see the divider between Header and Menu item is sky blue color (purple) . And the Title color also same color. So how can I change title text color and Divider line color from sky blue to RED?
Thanks in Advance

Code is here

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuInfoIn) {

    menu.add(0, PLAY_SELECTION, 0, R.string.play_selection);
    SubMenu sub = menu.addSubMenu(0, ADD_TO_PLAYLIST, 0, R.string.add_to_playlist);
    MusicUtils.makePlaylistMenu(this, sub);
    menu.add(0, DELETE_ITEM, 0, R.string.delete_item);

    AdapterContextMenuInfo mi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfoIn;
    mAlbumCursor.moveToPosition(mi.position);
    mCurrentAlbumId = mAlbumCursor.getString(mAlbumCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID));
    mCurrentAlbumName = mAlbumCursor.getString(mAlbumCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM));
    mCurrentArtistNameForAlbum = mAlbumCursor.getString(
            mAlbumCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST));
    mIsUnknownArtist = mCurrentArtistNameForAlbum == null ||
            mCurrentArtistNameForAlbum.equals(MediaStore.UNKNOWN_STRING);
    mIsUnknownAlbum = mCurrentAlbumName == null ||
            mCurrentAlbumName.equals(MediaStore.UNKNOWN_STRING);
    if (mIsUnknownAlbum) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle(getString(R.string.unknown_album_name));
    } else {
        menu.setHeaderTitle(mCurrentAlbumName);
    }
    if (!mIsUnknownAlbum || !mIsUnknownArtist) {
        menu.add(0, SEARCH, 0, R.string.search_title);
    }
}
```

Comment: menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.icon);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android/13342157#13342157

Comment: I dont want to set the Header Icons. I want the divider line to be RED which comes between the Header and Menu Item

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-context-menus--mobile-8845

Comment: ok see the last link and see this also http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/01/creating-context-menu-in-android.html

Comment: Consider posting your codes for this as well, otherwise it seems a low quality post.

Comment: @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuInfoIn) {
        menu.add(0, PLAY_SELECTION, 0, R.string.play_selection);
        SubMenu sub = menu.addSubMenu(0, ADD_TO_PLAYLIST, 0, R.string.add_to_playlist);
        MusicUtils.makePlaylistMenu(this, sub);
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ITEM, 0, R.string.delete_item);

Comment: Add this code to your **question**, so that it can appear **formatted**.

Comment: The code in question is for creating a Context Menu when i long press on any of song in Music Player.

Comment: Pragna, please read the question more closely and stop posting links. He is not asking for general tutorials on creating context menus, he is asking very specifically how to change the header text and divider color.